# How to exit downloadHandler when file doesn't exist

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app with a `downloadButton`, which enables the user to download some log files.

As the logfiles are also handled by logrotate, it might be that at a certain time no logfile exists, which currently breaks the app when trying to download it.

How can I prevent that? Or how can I display a `modalDialog` with the information, that no log-file currently exists?

I tried to include `req(F)` or `return(FALSE)` but they don't work.
The current approach works, as I create an empty data.frame which is then exported, but it's not a very nice solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

## Write random log file. Uncomment the next line to make the example work.
#fwrite(x = iris, file = "logs.log")


ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("showLogs", label="", title="Logs herunterladen", icon = icon("book-open"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$showLogs <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('logs-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      logfile <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = basename("logs.log"))
      if (length(logfile) != 0) {
        logfile <- fread(logfile, sep = ";", header = F)
        fwrite(logfile, file, sep = ";", row.names = FALSE)
      } else {
        ## Problem is in here
        # req(F)
        # return(FALSE)
        fwrite(data.frame("No log-Files"), file, sep = ";", row.names = FALSE)
      }
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Maybe use  `shinyjs::enable` and `shinyjs::disable` to disable the download button if no file exists.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but that would mean I would have to include another `observe` to check if a log-file exists or not. Isn't there an option to break out of the `downloadHandler` content function?

Comment: I'd argue that having a broken button (one that when pushed before a log file is present, does nothing) is the worse option here, even if it means more coding.

Comment: I would rather like to display a notification that says "No log files" instead of breaking the app and creating an error. So pressing the button wouldn't do nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without `reactiveTimer`.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(shinyjs)

## Write random log file. Uncomment the next line to make the example work.
#fwrite(x = iris, file = "logs.log")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  downloadButton("showLogs", label="", style = "display:none;"),
  actionButton("btn", "Download") 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    logfile <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = basename("logs.log"))
    if(length(logfile)){
      runjs("$('#showLogs').click();")
    }
  })

  output$showLogs <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('logs-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      logfile <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = basename("logs.log"))
      logfile <- fread(logfile, sep = ";", header = F)
      fwrite(logfile, file, sep = ";", row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: For some reason the indirect click, doesn't trigger a download on my machine (initial `fwrite` was uncommented). When I display the actual `downloadButton` and click it directly the download works. I also tried to use `click("showLogs")` instead of `runjs` - same behaviour. What am I missing here?

Comment: @ismirsehregal This worked for me. But now that does not work anymore... I have updated Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This app throws an alert if you click the button while no log file exists, and there's no download.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(shinyjs)

## Write random log file. Uncomment the next line to make the example work.
#fwrite(x = iris, file = "logs.log")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  downloadButton("showLogs", label="", title="Logs herunterladen", icon = icon("book-open"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(1000)

  observe({
    autoInvalidate()
    logfile <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = basename("logs.log"))
    if(length(logfile)){
      runjs("$('#showLogs').off('click.x')")
    }else{
      runjs("$('#showLogs').off('click.x').on('click.x', function(e){alert('No log file'); e.preventDefault();})")
    }
  })

  output$showLogs <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('logs-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      logfile <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = basename("logs.log"))
      logfile <- fread(logfile, sep = ";", header = F)
      fwrite(logfile, file, sep = ";", row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This works, but I would prefer to not include a `reactiveTimer` function which runs repeatedly. I was hoping, that I could exit the downloadHandler from inside itself.